# Is it possible to query attributes from objects in lists on DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have this JSON structure on my dataset to a Japanese dictionary (it has more entities, but the snippet will do as example):

```
"id" : 1259290, 
"kanji" : [ {
  "common" : true, 
  "text" : "見る", 
  "tags" : [  ]
}, {
  "common" : false, 
  "text" : "観る", 
  "tags" : [  ]
}, {
  "common" : false, 
  "text" : "視る", 
  "tags" : [  ]
} ], 
"kana" : [ {
  "common" : true, 
  "text" : "みる", 
  "tags" : [  ], 
  "appliesToKanji" : [ "*" ]
} ]
```

An unique word can have many readings and many types of readings. My objective is to make a search tool that will search for the correct word based on three aspects of the word: the text on the objects on "kanji" list, the text on objects on the "kana" list and the meaning in English, which is not shown in the example, but it is basically the same as the other two. The user could input any of the three and the results would appear transparently.

I cannot find a good solution for the problem using DynamoDB however, since using the sort key doesn't look feasible and there isn't any examples on the documentation for filter and [items attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Attributes.html) that seems to fit, none of them seems to iterate through the list to find the object or something similar.  I thought some solutions and I would like to understand if they are feasible:

1) Make 4 tables separating the word readings possibilities and meanings and using the text as Hash Key. It looks expensive to query all tables to do a simple search though.

2) Concatenate the text attributes from the various objects and make them available as sort key or string attribute to be more easily queryable. The table will have redundant information though.

3) Creating GSIs so that I would be able to query with the attributes needed, but by what I can see it is not possible given that they are inside a list. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

4) Any combination of the three that solve the problem.

Which should be a good solution? Any better suggestions would also be valuable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an interesting question. Option #1 seems to be the "right" one but option #2 is faster of course.

Also, you could also combine 2 & 3, i.e., use a GSI for the concatenated `text` attributes instead of a sort key. This way, you can always get the item knowing the `id` only or query the table knowing the `text` only. (And you're right regarding point 3 by the way)

Another ugly approach you might want to consider is a recursive [Scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) (using `LastEvaluatedKey`/`ExclusiveStartKey`). It does not require you to change your current table design though but it'd be slow of course. Since you cannot filter the result before it's returned using the `text` attribute, you can filter the kanji/kana/meaning arrays after the result is returned in your code and run the next scan operation if no match was found and `LastEvaluatedKey` is present in the response. See [Paginating the Results](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.Pagination) for more details.

Comment: Thank for the answer! I think I will try a combination of 2 & 3 first and then if it doesn't work, I will use the first option. The option you said it is ugly would be the last options possible, I want to avoid scan as much as possible. Later on I will post the results. Thanks again!

Comment: One thing I noticed though is that doesn't GSI Hash Key needs a exact match to get the item? The concatanation of the text fields would be done with the idea of using "contains" or any kind of Regex if possible. Isn't using the concatanation of the text fields ruining this goal?

Comment: You're absolutely right. The concatenation approach won't work unless you know all the text values in advance.

Comment: Then I will have to do the second approach alone. Maybe I can think of any GSI to help later, but that's it for now,  I think. Create the first scenario for test purposes is not a bad idea either. 
Thanks again for the answer!